# Windows, starting a service each time another starts

Tags: windows, service

I need to start a service B only after service A is started, and each time it is started. I tried doing this using the 'dependencies', but this only works during the boot. The problem is that using the dependencies, if I stop the service A, service B also stops which is fine for my purposes, but whenever I start service A, B should be also started and it is not.

Is there a ways to achieve this with the normal windows service manager?

Comment: If B depends on A, then it is not true that starting A should start B.  (Instead, starting B should start A.)  If A depends on B, then it is not true that stopping A should stop B.  And if they are mutually dependent, then they shouldn't be two separate services is the first place.  Which is it?

Comment: I need that each time service A starts, service B is started as well and if service A stops, then service B must be stopped.

Comment: So at any given time, either both A and B are running or neither is running?  There's no way to do that, because after all, there's no point.  Instead, combine A and B into a single service.